# Can't delete data in Laravels

Tags: laravel, sql-delete

I will delete data by id but, the button is not working when I cick to delete.
I need you help.

### Here's my view

```
 @foreach ($books as $books)
           <tr>
              <td>{{$books->id}}</td>
              <td>{{$books->name}}</td>
              <td>{{$books->year}}</td>
              <td>{{$books->publisher}}</td>
              <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" title="details"><i class="fa fa-info" ></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" title="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i><a href ="{{ route('deletebook',[$books->id])}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this book?')"></a></button>
             </td>
          </tr>
@endforeach
```

here's my controller

```
 public function deleteBook($id) {
   DB::table('books')->where('id', $id)->delete();
   return redirect('home')->with('status', 'DELETE succesfully'); }
```

here's my route

```
Route::delete('/deleteBook/{id}','BooksController@deleteBook')->name('deletebook');
```

I want to use button with icon like that, and i want to delete the data using that button, but when i clicked its not working. Do you have any solution?
Thank you

Comment: Unclear. What error are you getting on your screen or logs? Try putting your query in a try...catch block to see if it's throwing some exception.

Comment: A button itself will do nothing, you'd need Javascript or a form to submit data. And `<a>` inside a `<button>` will also do nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

At the blade (view)

```
<form action="{{ route('deletebook',[$books->id])}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('delete')
  <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this book?')" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></button>
</form>
```

Note: The form is a display block you can change to inline by adding this class `d-inline`

Route

```
Route::delete('/deleteBook/{book}','BooksController@deleteBook')->name('deletebook');
```

Controller

```
//Add Book model
public function deleteBook(Book $book) {
   $book->delete();
   return redirect('home')->with('status', 'DELETE succesfully'); 
}
```

Try it, and tell me if is everything alright.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Hello @Mohammed Gamal Eldin, thank you for your help, I try the code but not use the Model and now my code can run well :))

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy is everything went well.